# Multiple file attachment in mail using php Blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: php, email, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm working with a long form(ajax/php) now I want to send multiple images using blueimp file upload. 
 I need to figure out how I can send those images as an attachment after user hits submit. 
If someone has similar experience pls help me out.

If you can suggest any alternate to multiple image upload using ajax/php I'll be more than happy to use it. Thanks
All i'm looking for is to send those uploaded images as an attachment using php/ajax..! 
Its a long form with many inputs "name, mobile, date, and some 10 other fields most of them text fields except few checkbox " the form is working fine till now all i'm looking to add on more field to "Add files" with blueimp-jq-upload 
all I need to figure out now is a way to add uploaded images to my php mail function.

Comment: can you provide the response json data

Comment: Fixed json error looking to attach images to php mail.